# Get XML values into combobox

Tags: c#, xml, combobox

Basically, I'm trying to read a XML file and insert data into the combobox, but either it gets just the fist value or it gets all three values into just one row.

Code:

```
foreach (var NomeProcesso in doc.Descendants("Processo")){
            comboBoxProcessos.Items.Add(NomeProcesso.Element("NomeProcesso").Value);}
```

I expected the combobox giving me all 3 processes in different rows

But all I got in the end was either just process1

or

process1process2process3 (It happens if I change the code to "Arquitetura" instead of "Processo" and "Processo" instead of "NomeProcesso")

XML:

```
<!-- language: lang-xml -->
<Arquitetura>
  <NomeArquitetura>Teste</NomeArquitetura>
  <VersaoArquitetura>1</VersaoArquitetura>
  <Ator />
  <Atividade />
  <Processo>
    <NomeProcesso>process1</NomeProcesso>
    <NomeProcesso>process2</NomeProcesso>
    <NomeProcesso>process3</NomeProcesso>
  </Processo>
  <Operacao />
  <Fase />
  <Software />
  <Informacao />
  <Ato />
</Arquitetura>
```

Comment: Please show all code.

Comment: You probably want `foreach (var item in doc.Descendants("NomeProcesso")){comboBoxProcessos.Items.Add(item.Value);}`

Comment: Use following : foreach (var NomeProcesso in doc.Descendants("NomeProcesso")){
            comboBoxProcessos.Items.Add((string)NomeProcesso);}

Comment: jdweng, it worked perfectly. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The user [jdweng](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5015238/jdweng) just commented the post and it worked like a charm. Thank you so much!!

```
foreach (var NomeProcesso in doc.Descendants("NomeProcesso")){ comboBoxProcessos.Items.Add((string)NomeProcesso);}
```

Answer (score -1):

If you are using XmlDocument try:

```
 foreach(XmlNode node in xmlDocument.GetElementsByTagName("Processo"))
 {
     comboBoxProcessos.Items.Add(node.InnerText);
 }
```